# GROUP BY error in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error

> Column 'tbl_user.u_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I'm doing this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    tbl_user 
JOIN 
    tbl_assign_role ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
WHERE   
    is_active = 1 
    AND u_id != 1 
    AND tar_is_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY 
    tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
ORDER BY 
    tbl_user.u_updated_date DESC
```

Comment: You can't use `SELECT *` in `GROUP BY` statements. You must explicitly declare the columns you want to return, and those columns must either be aggregate values (e.g. `SUM`) or columns listed in your `GROUP BY` expression.

Comment: give column names in select or just remove the group by in select list

Comment: As stated in the error: > All columns in the `SELECT` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: When I do that It made duplicate results

Answer (score 0):

Strongly agreed with @Dai

According to me, you should read first the role of "Group By". Here in your query there is no any aggregate function used, so there is no case here to use "Group By".

Comment: When I remove the group by I'm receiving 300+ results while in mysql when I tried that query it only gave me 20 results (the one with the group by)

Comment: firstly do the assign proper tag. you have tagged sqlserver while you are saying mysql. You are misguiding, who are willing to help you. And for further assistance, required both table structure and some sample data of both the tables.

Comment: What I'm doing is converting my mysql db to mssql.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, to continue removing duplicates while not needing the group by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT --[INSERT NEEDED COLUMNS HERE]
FROM
    tbl_user 
JOIN 
    tbl_assign_role ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
WHERE   
    is_active = 1 
    AND u_id != 1 
    AND tar_is_deleted = 0 
ORDER BY 
    tbl_user.u_updated_date DESC
```

Comment: I'm still receiving duplicated from that query